# Oracle SQL count cases by one column

Tags: sql, oracle, count

In oracle SQL I have a table, FINAL, like such :

```
--------------------
--  ID      -- TYPE
--------------------
-- 123      -- A
-- 123      -- A
-- 123      -- B
-- 123      -- B
-- 123      -- C
-- 124      -- B
-- 124      -- B
-- 124      -- C
-- ...      -- ...
```

and I would like an output like such:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Count distinct IDs -- count (type A) -- count (type B) -- count (type C)
-- 10000              -- 5000           -- 4000           -- 1000
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The part I am having trouble with is that once an ID is counted type A, it cannot be B or C. Once it is counted type B, it cannot be C and can't have been A. To be C, it must ever have been counted A or B.

Thus far I have something like

```
select
count(distinct FINAL.ID)
from 
FINAL
```

A, B, and C are the only possible values.

Comment: Are A, B and C the only possible values? If there are also other values possible, do you only need to count A, B and C? (If the answer to **both** questions is **no** then what you want may not be possible without dynamic SQL).

Comment: A, B, and C are the only possible values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this may work:

```
select count(*) as ct_id,
       count(case type when 'A' then 1 end) as ct_a,
       count(case type when 'B' then 1 end) as ct_b,
       count(case type when 'C' then 1 end) as ct_c
from (
       select   id, min(type) as type
       from     final
       group by id
     )
;
```

The subquery takes care of "distinct" (because it generates a single row for each distinct `id`), and it selects just the "least" `type` for each `id`. The outer query does the total count and the conditional counts.